# Rounding numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers

The results of my function is like this.0.702568.but I want 0.70257.i can not use round function. Is there  solution for this problem?

Comment: Re: "i can not use round function": Why not? What happens when you try?

Comment: Also -- do you actually want your function to return the numeric value `0.70257`, or do you just want to *display* a rounded value? For the latter case, you should use `sprintf` to control the display.

Comment: because the result became 1 and it is not The correct answer.i want  to use  the result of this function in this form for another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using sleight of hand. If you want to round your number `x` to the `kth` decimal place you do something like

```
xrk = round(x*10^k)/10^k;
```

In your instance `k = 5`.